# Sapling tree to a mesh and follow the treeArm Animation like the leaves?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

The tree is a curve and has a windSway modifier. The leaves is a mesh and has a windSway modifier. How I convert the tree to a mesh and make it to follow treeArm & animation like the leaves?

Comment: Convert it to a mesh using Alt-C. But I'm not sure if the modified data will stay intact.

Comment: I know how to convert to a mesh, but the windSway modifier is lost then and it cannot be found in the modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and I just found out the solution. In the Operator panel for the Sapling, simply check the "Make Mesh" box in the Armature menu and there you go! If you want to edit the mesh, you have to look for the Skin modifier that is created in the Outline under's the tree's mesh and apply it.

Hope this solves your problem!